# INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, encryptor_registered_name=configurationHibernateEncryptor, password=****}

Tags: java, hibernate, encriptación, jasypt

Hola he querido encriptar la clave que tengo hacia la base de datos en el archivo hibernate.cfg.xml, y encontré *Jasypt* lo puede hacer, he seguido estos tutoriales.

http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html

http://java-rd.blogspot.mx/2012/07/encrypting-hibernate-configuration-file.html

He usado el encrypt.bat y metiéndole los parámetros para que me devuelva la clave de la base de datos encriptada, la configuración de mi archivo hibernate.cfg.xml quedo de esta manera:

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.jasypt.hibernate4.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider</property>

<property name="connection.encryptor_registered_name">configurationHibernateEncryptor</property> 
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aprendiendojsf?autoReconnect=true</property> 
    <property name="connection.username">root</property> 
    <property name="connection.password">ENC(lhFCMXdRkAw7Cz5JU17lvg==)</property> 
    <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Mi clase *HibernateUtil* de esta manera:

```
public class HibernateUtil { 

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null; 

    static { 
        try { 
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml)  
            // config file. 
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 

            StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor(); 
            encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES"); 
            encryptor.setPassword("clave"); 
            HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry = HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance(); 
            registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("configurationHibernateEncryptor", encryptor); 
            } catch (Throwable ex) { 
            // Log the exception.  
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex); 
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() { 
        return sessionFactory; 
    } 
}
```

Mi proyecto levanta de manera correcta, pero al momento de hacer el login, en el log aparece esto:

> INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, encryptor_registered_name=configurationHibernateEncryptor, password=****}
>
> WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

No entiendo que pueda estar pasando, ya tengo 3 días en esto y no logro dar, ojala me puedan ayudar, me seria de gran ayuda!

He hecho el siguiente cambio en la clase Hibernate Util, el cual me sugirieron.

```
public class HibernateUtil { 

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
 

    static { 
    try { 

  

      EnvironmentStringPBEConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
      envConfig.setPasswordEnvName(“DB_SIMETRIC_KEY”);

      sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 

      StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor(); 
      encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES"); 
      encryptor.setConfig(envConfig); 

      HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry = HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance(); 
      registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("configurationHibernateEncryptor", encryptor); 
    } catch (Throwable ex) { 
      // Log the exception.  
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex); 
      ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  

    } 
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() { 
    return sessionFactory; 
 

     } 
}
```

Sin embargo la consola de apache me lanza lo mismo:

> WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Pensé que era mas fácil la configuración.

Comment: Hola @Abner bienvenido al sitio. Por favor indica si utilizas Hibernate 3 o 4 y si utilizas algún otro framework adicional por ejemplo Spring y algún framework para pool de conexiones como HikariCP o C3PO

Comment: Esto es aparte de lo que preguntas, pero te recomendaría que tengas **muchísimo** cuidado con Jasypt y no lo uses a menos de que hayas consultado con un experto en seguridad sobre cuales opciones usar.  En particular, en tu ejemplo usas `PBEWithMD5AndDES`, pero [desde hace ya más de 20 años se sabe que el algoritmo DES es inseguro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker).  Yo diría que a pesar de parecer muy sencilla, Jasypt es una librería que se ha quedado muy atrás con los años—las opciones por defecto son espantosas!

Answer (score 0):

Debes definir una variable a nivel de sistema con el valor para que realice la encriptación de la password de base de datos. Cuando utilizaste `encript.bat` introdujiste un valor para realizar para obtener `lhFCMXdRkAw7Cz5JU17lvg==` mediante el algoritmo indicado *PBEWithMD5AndDES*.

Por ejemplo, pongo un variable de sistema con ese valor llamada ***DB_SIMETRIC_KEY=tu valor***.

Ahora la clase pasa a ser así:

```
public class HibernateUtil { 

  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null; 

  static { 
    try { 

      EnvironmentStringPBEConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
      envConfig.setPasswordEnvName(“DB_SIMETRIC_KEY”);

      sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 

      StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor(); 
      encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES"); 
      encryptor.setConfig(envConfig); 

      HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry = HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance(); 
      registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("configurationHibernateEncryptor", encryptor); 
    } catch (Throwable ex) { 
      // Log the exception.  
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex); 
      ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  } 

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() { 
    return sessionFactory; 
  } 

}
```

Arranca tu aplicación y pon el valor de la variable de sistema a *null*. De esta forma `lhFCMXdRkAw7Cz5JU17lvg==` será desencriptado por su clave simétrica ***DB_SIMETRIC_KEY*** obteniendo el valor la password con el cual te conectas.